# Javascript - View all pages in one

Tags: javascript, url

So I have this:

```
www.example.com/test.html?id=0&page=1
```

and I want with javascript to get the contents of all pages..

I tried this:

```
www.example.com/test.html?id=0&page=1&page=2
```

but it just displays the first page

How can I make it display all the pages in one page?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be easily possible as it depends on the code of test.html and how that page handles the [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). One way to do this is to construct your own html page which will load all pages in [iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_src.asp). Like so:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test/?page=1"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test/?page=2"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test/?page=3"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ok but how can I use the getElementById in iframe?

Comment: that is a different question, please ask a new one or search stackoverflow for "iframe getelementbyid" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022464/getelementbyid-within-iframe (and mark this answer as answered if it is)